# Without government, wouldn't warlords take over?

Tags: military, anarchism, borders, police, anarcho-capitalism

In an [Anarcho-capitalist](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anarcho-capitalism) society, where there is no government, wouldn't warlords of competing factions take over?

Comment: Yes, obviously.

Comment: Warlords are a type of government. If I can include types of government, I say global imperial domination

Comment: Robert Murphy has a great write-up on why the answer is "not necessarily" here: https://mises.org/daily/1855

Comment: This is the result that is almost always predicted in Post-Apocolyptic SciFi.  Though I am not certian what the point of this question is.  I think the question needs to be refined to work well on SE.

Comment: They must compete on free market, according to [NAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-aggression_principle). Otherwise they will be expelled from an-cap society.

Comment: Someone is far too invested in The Badlands.